# ～といわず、～といわず with 否定文

Tags: usage, phrases

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that 「～といわず、～といわず」 doesn't come in 否定文, but I came across negative usage of late. Research took me to [this site](https://chiyo-sampo.net/grammar-jlptn1-toiwazu-toiwazu/) maintained by a native speaking Japanese teacher who claims:

> 後件は否定文、依頼、命令の文はきません。

Okay, great. Wait, what's that in your examples?

> 部長は食事中といわず、会議中といわず、スマホを手離さない。

Literally two lines below, that page uses a 否定文 as an example sentence.

Here's another example I found, in a work of fiction translated by [菊池寛](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8F%8A%E6%B1%A0%E5%AF%9B).

> ネルロの行くところは野と言わず、市場の人混みと言わず、片時もそばをはなれないことにきめたのでした。([source](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001044/files/4880_13769.html))

So what's with this talk about ～といわず、～といわず not occurring in 否定文?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are any requirement in X of 'AといわずBといわずX'.
My feeling is that acceptability depends only on the meaning.

The pattern means literally *regardless of A or B, X*.

For example,  both of the following are not acceptable.

> 食事中といわず、会議中といわず、スマホを手離す。
>
> 昼といわず、夜といわず、彼と一緒にいない。

It is because not having a phone or not being with someone else is rather normal and not worth mentioning.

On the other hand

> 猫といわず犬といわず動物は何でも好きです
>
> 猫といわず犬といわず動物は何でも好きじゃないです

are both acceptable (even though the latter sounds less natural - apart from such a person being unfortunate; probably 嫌いです would be more natural instead of 好きじゃないです.). This is due to the fact that both types of people are conceivable.

Answer (score 2):

ＡといわずＢといわず basically means *everything*, *everywhere*, *all the time*, etc. A and B are just examples. It is used to describe the way someone *does* something, and therefore, it is normally not used in a negative sentence.

I think this rule applies on the semantic level. Though syntactically negative, 手離さない and はなれない in your examples both indirectly describe the way someone, or a dog, does something anytime or anywhere. The department manager is always on their smartphone, and the dog is determined to stay close to Nello everywhere he goes.